# Use regex to split a string by {curly} substrings but include the { }

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string:

`var s = "Cat{biscuits}Flaps";`

Output should be:

> Cat 
> {biscuits} 
> Flaps

I can iterate over this:

`Regex.Split(input, @"{(?<p>[^}]*)}");`

However it removes the { } from biscuits

Can you suggest a regex that includes the { } to give the output above?

Comment: Place the parentheses outside of the curly braces to capture those too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a capturing group around the whole pattern:

```
var chunks = Regex.Split(input, @"({[^}]*})");
                                  ^       ^
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/AifPx0):

```
var s = "Cat{biscuits}Flaps";
var chunks = Regex.Split(s, @"({[^}]*})");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", chunks));
```

See [`Regex.Split` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If capturing parentheses are used in a [Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d(v=vs.110).aspx) expression, any captured text is included in the resulting string array.

Comment: Great, thanks. Somehow I got muddled up with my brackets and this has cracked it.