# Issue with Regex.Split

Tags: c#, regex

So I was trying to check whether a string follows a pattern like this one:`abbccc`, where every letter occurs as many times as its set position indicates. So I thought about splitting the string with this pattern: `(?<=(\w))(?=\w)(?!\1)` and go on from there. The problem is that, for the above string in particular (but for others too), I get 5 strings with `Regex.Split` : `a, a, bb, b, ccc`, instead of `a, bb, ccc`, how I'd expect. I thought there was a problem with the regex, but `Regex.Replace` worked fine, returning `a_bb_ccc`. What could be the problem?

Comment: You overcomplicate it with `Regex.Split` (there is a capturing group, that captured value also becomes a part of the resulting array). Use `Regex.Matches(s, @"(\w)\1*").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList()`

Comment: If replace works can't you replace and then split ion `_` ?

Comment: @EpicKip of course, but that wasn't my question.

Comment: Please precise what you are interested in, a solution, an explanation why you get more values in the output array, or both? What is the expected result for `!@#abb--ccc33`?

Comment: Actually, @EpicKip idea might be the best in this situation. Just choose a symbol that is not usually used, something like `\u200C` (ZWNJ) to replace with and then split on.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the string will only contain letters

Comment: Then, Rizwan's and my suggestions will work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `that captured value also becomes a part of the resulting array`. How so?

Comment: @NotADeveloper It has been already explained on SO. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595675/use-regex-to-split-a-string-by-curly-substrings-but-include-the/39595770#39595770) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that :

```
(.)\1*
```

you get 3 match a, bb, ccc

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vKXhcJ/1/)

Sample Source ( [run here](https://ideone.com/nLbOve) )

```
    string pattern = @"(.)\1*";
    string input = @"abbccc";

    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
        Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```